# Tensorboard callback on keras gives InvalidArgumentError when training multiple networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard

I have a method `train_model` which gets a keras model object as input and trains it. I have a loop somewhere else in my code that creates a new model in each iteration and passes it to this method. If I don't pass a TensorBoard Callback my code works fine. However, when I do pass the TensorBoard Callback, the first network gets trained but for the second one I get this error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_7_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
>        [[{{node dense_7_target}} = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

after calling `.fit` method. (the network i'm building is 5 layers)

and there is more unexpected behaviors:
When I run this code for a second time, the first network won't need training (since I have already saved the model and it will just load that) and the second network gets trained with no errors but I get the same error for the third network.

In this case, when I check the TensorBoard graphs, I see that the first network has been created correctly, but the second network has twice the layers it should have (as if the first model has been loaded first and then the second network was built on it).
here is my `train_model` method:

```
def train_model(model, data, dataname, MODEL_DIR, LOG_DIR, BS, EP, callbacks):
X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data
if not os.path.exists(MODEL_DIR):
    os.makedirs(MODEL_DIR)
model_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(MODEL_DIR + dataname + '/',
                                                    monitor='mse',
                                                    verbose=1,
                                                    save_weights_only=True)
tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LOG_DIR + dataname,histogram_freq=10)
callbacks += [model_callback, tb_callback]
if not os.path.exists(MODEL_DIR + dataname + '/'):
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=BS, epochs=EP, verbose=0, callbacks=callbacks, validation_split=0.2)
validation_split=0.2)
    else:
        model.load_weights(MODEL_DIR + dataname + '/')
    return model
```

I have done everything I could and i'm really out of ideas about what's wrong with my code.

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.